# How can I convert Geometry data into a Geography data in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geometry, geography

How can I convert some Geometry data into Geography data in MS SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can but the geometry datatype is more forgiving than the geography in my experience.  So there is some data you might have in geometry that you can't convert.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/edkatibah/archive/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b.aspx) from Spatial Ed was very helpful explaining how to fix data problems and also has some sample queries to convert from Geom to Geog.

Comment: No offense, but "link only" answers are frowned upon and I think it would be better to answer the question.

Comment: Especially seeing that the link now produces "Oops! That page can’t be found.
This page has been disabled."

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer really. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200746/convert-geography-to-geometry-sql-server-2008r2) instead

Comment: For those that care, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100226221322/http://blogs.msdn.com/edkatibah/archive/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b.aspx) is the wayback machine link for that Spatial Ed article